# print response from post request

Tags: python

I am trying to print response from a post request in python. Response shall be print in list. I tried the below code but i only get status code 200. Need help to print response body as per screenshot below .

```
import requests
r = requests.get('URL')
print r.json
```

[API Response Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMow0.png)

Comment: if you get a response Code 200 it all went fine. Try to output the text like this:
`print r.text`

Comment: If you're expecting to see the json response... then you need to call `.json`, eg: `print r.json()`...

Comment: getting error on r.json() -> simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: add headers an change method to post, `r = requests.post('url', headers={'content-type':'application/json'})`

Comment: it also didnt print the value, just gives the status

Answer (score 4):

Patrick, I hope this code can help you:

```
import requests
import json
import pprint

r = requests.get('URL')
pprint.pprint(json.loads(r.content))
```

pprint is only to see the output, I guess the main point for you are the `json.loads` and `r.content`.

Best Regards!